# I don't know how to use gnuplot datafile

Tags: gnuplot

I have an assignment in which i had to execute a function from a library and my version of it on 3 architectures, nehalem ,opteron and quad. And i have obtained for each architecture my running time, and the actual function's running time. Now i have to create some plots with gnuplot to make a comparison between them, but im not sure how to use it. I need some help in setting up the data file and how the plot command will look like. Let's say i have this data file (not sure how to write it to work):

N=10000 (this is the order of the matrix)

For nehalem : my_time cblas_tyme optimized_time

For opteron: my_time cblas_time optimized_time

For quad: my_time cblas_time optimized_time.

This should result in a grafic showing how long it took to compute a matrix of 10000x10000 on all architectures with different functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to plot a bar graph.

Data File example:

```
"my_time nehalem" 100 
"cblas_tyme nehalem" 120
"optimized_time nehalem" 100 
"my_time opteron" 200
"cblas_tyme opteron" 222
"optimized_time opteron" 202
"my_time quad" 103
"cblas_tyme quad" 100
"optimized_time quad" 99
```

You can plot this using:

```
plot "data.dat" using 2:xtic(1) with histogram
```

See [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.html) for more histogram examples and [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node249.html) to learn more.

**Edit:**

Addressing your comment, you might want to use a data file (say data.dat) similar to this:

```
N simple-quad simple-nehalem simple-opteron alt-quad alt-nehalem alt-opteron
10000 2  3  3  2  7  7  
15000 5  4  4  7  14 14 
20000 10 12 12 15 17 20
```

You can plot this with the following script:

```
set autoscale y
set autoscale x
set grid
set xtic auto
set ytic auto
set xlabel "N"
set ylabel "Time"
plot "data.dat" every ::1 using 1:2 title "simple-quad" with linespoints, \
"data.dat" every ::1 using 1:3 title "simple-nehalem" with linespoints \
"data.dat" every ::1 using 1:4 title "simple-opteron" with linespoints \
"data.dat" every ::1 using 1:5 title "alt-quad" with linespoints \
"data.dat" every ::1 using 1:6 title "alt-nehalem" with linespoints \
"data.dat" every ::1 using 1:7 title "alt-opteron" with linespoints
```

Comment: Thank you good sir, as soon as i get a spare moment and try it ,i will chose your answer

Comment: I have another question if you dont mind helping me once more. I want to make an overall performance curve like here http://ge.tt/1ukYnPd/v/0 . I want on the Xaxis to have values of N and on the Y axis the time it took. How would i change the data file, and what settings in gnuplot ? SO i'll have for my nehalem, my opteron, my quad, the time it took for N=10,000 -> N=30.000, with a pace of 5000

Comment: @user1272703 Edited my answer. The script is pretty self-explanatory, but I'll be happy to offer explanations if you'd like some. Also, remember that Google is your friend. ;)

Comment: Yes thank you, i already managed to do it, but your input is much appreciated. A good day to you